# Modifying Matplotlib multicoloured histogram script to make it cumulative

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I was trying to make histograms where different bars are different colours. I was delighted to find [this page](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/1D-and-2D-histograms-using-numpy-and-matplotlib-tt12502.html#none) which provided scripts to do it all for me. There's only one problem - it doesn't seem to support cumulative histograms, like you can do by adding "cumulative=True" in the regular Matplotlib histograms.
Could someone tell me how to modify [this file](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/file/n12502/histogram.py) to let me plot cumulative, multicoloured histograms?
Thanks a lot,
Alex

EDIT: What I think would be the best solution would be adding a function to the histogram class saying something like this:

```
def make_cumulative(self):
  self.occurrences = np.cumsum(self.occurrences)
```

But I don't know what occurrences is being stored as, or even if it makes sense to think of it as a parameter that way.

Comment: What have you tried?  Show us what you have tried that _hasn't_ worked and we can help you fix it.

Comment: Well it's a little embarrassing what I tried, I thought "oh, I just need to cumsum the input data. So I did that and it became immediately obvious that I didn't need to cumsum the input data, I needed to cumsum the occurrences. I went to the histogram.py file and tried to find out what it calls occurrences but couldn't find it anywhere. It looks like it might be histogram.h or histogram.e in the object, but I don't really know.

Comment: You need to provide more context.  Does it give you errors when you use that code? What is `self.occurrences` defined as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was very simple and obvious in hindsight. The histogram object is just an array of the occurrences of each bin, so I just took the cumsum of the histogram itself.

So basically

```
import histogram, numpy 
y = range(0, 100) #Except I used real data
Hist = histogram(y, bins=100, range=[0,100])
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', ]
ranges = [[0,30], [30,31], [31,100]]
fig = pyplot.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax, plt, _ = fig.plothist(Hist, alpha=0) # plot for spacing
for c, r in zip(colors, ranges):
    plt = ax.overlay(Hist, range=r, facecolor=c)
print y

CumulativeHist = numpy.cumsum(h6)
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', ]
ranges = [[0,30], [30,31], [31,100]]
fig = pyplot.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax, plt, _ = fig.plothist(CumulativeHist, alpha=0) # plot for spacing
for c, r in zip(colors, ranges):
    plt = ax.overlay(CumulativeHist, range=r, facecolor=c)

pyplot.show()
```

Will make two plots, the second of which is the cumulative version of the second.
Thanks for the help.

Alex

Comment: One other note, much smaller bins can be used for the cumulative plot, so it might be best to run a version with 'bins = 1000' or something similarly big. That way you get more of a smooth curve, rather than clunky steps up.